# Program runs only with multiprocessing.dummy

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am uploading a file in parallel to an `amazon s3 bukcet`. I have the code working exactly for to my needs. For debugging purposes I was using `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool`. Now that the program works, i got rid of the `.dummy` and only using `from multiprocessing import Pool`. However after this small change my file upload fails (jumps to 'File upload canceled' under else). I am not sure what seems to be the issue. Posted below is a the code. I have edited out most of the irrelevant parts.

```
def multipart_upload(bucketname, keyname, parallel_processes=5):
    """
    Parallel multipart upload.
    """
    source_size = os.stat(keyname).st_size
    mp = bucket.initiate_multipart_upload( keyname )
    bytes_per_chunk = max(int(math.sqrt(5242880) * math.sqrt(source_size)),
                          5242880)
    chunk_amount = int(math.ceil(source_size / float(bytes_per_chunk)))

    def _upload(keyname, offset, part_num,bytes):
        try:
            print( 'Start uploading part #%d ...' % part_num )
            with FileChunkIO(keyname, 'r', offset=offset,
                             bytes=bytes) as fp:
                mp.upload_part_from_file( fp=fp, part_num=part_num )
        except Exception as e:
            print( 'FAILED uploading part #%d' % part_num )
            raise e
        else:
            print( 'UPLOADED part #%d' % part_num ) 

    if s3_has_uptodate_file(bucketname, keyname):
        print ( 'File already present in bucket. Upload Cancelled')
        mp.cancel_upload()
    else:
        print ( 'File Upload begininning with {0} cores'.format( parallel_processes ) )
        pool = Pool(processes=parallel_processes)
        for i in range( chunk_amount ):
            offset = i * bytes_per_chunk
            remaining_bytes = source_size - offset
            bytes = min( [bytes_per_chunk, remaining_bytes] )
            part_num = i + 1
            start = timer()
            pool.apply_async( _upload, [keyname, offset, part_num, bytes] )
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        end = timer()

    if len( mp.get_all_parts() ) == chunk_amount:
        mp.complete_upload()
        print ( 'File Upload Complete\nTime taken {0} seconds'.format( end - start ) )
    else:
        print ( 'File Upload Cancelled' )
        mp.cancel_upload()  

multipart_upload(default_bucket, 'mybigfile.txt')
```

Comment: Use `pool.apply` instead of `pool.apply_async` and the error should appear. It's probably due to `_upload` not being defined at the top level of your module.

Comment: @dano Yeah . Its gives me a `cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed` error. How do I tackle it .

Comment: Can you define `_upload` at the top-level of your module, instead of inside `multipart_upload`?

Comment: ill try. I nested it inside my `multipart_upload` because when I had it outside i was running into issues